# DOM element move when clicking on a select input

Tags: jquery, select, input

When i'm clicking on my select #ajouterEmplacement it result in strange beavhior, he is moving left or the element just up him is moving left.

Here is the code from my function which display the select from the add button.

```
function displayGestionEmplacement(){
$("#deletePicture").css('visibility','hidden');
$("#popupDetailMoteur").attr('currentElementDisplayedType','gestionEmplacements');

// si on est en mode edition on rajoute l'option d'ajout d'un stock
if(modeEdition == true){
    var spanAddEmplacment='<span style="display:inline-block;border:1px solid white;margin:15px;padding:10px;">Nouvel emplacement <img id="imgAddEmplacement" style="cursor:pointer;vertical-align:middle;width:25px;width:25px;"src="images/ajouter.png"></span>';
}
else{
    var spanAddEmplacment = '';
}

$("#popupDetailMoteur").html('<img id="fermerPopupGestionMoteurs" src="./images/fermer.png" style="cursor:pointer;position:absolute;top:-12px;right:-12px;">'
    +'<div id="bodyPopup" style="text-align:center;padding:15px;border:1px solid white;background-color:#B9B0A1;">'
        +'<div><p><big><b>Emplacements moteurs</b></big></p></div>'
        +'<div id="mainStock"><span style="display:inline-block;background-color:rgb(180,175,145);cursor:pointer;border:1px solid white;margin:10px;padding:10px;">Usine de Sierre ASI</span></div>'
        +'<div niveau="0"> </div>'
        +'<div niveau="1"> </div>'
        +'<div niveau="2"> </div>'
        +'<div niveau="3"> </div>'
        +'<div niveau="4"> </div>'
        +'<div niveau="5"> </div>'
        +'<div id="ajouterEmplacement">'+spanAddEmplacment+'</div>'
    +'</div>');

//on affiche la gestion les emplacements de base
$("#mainStock").click(function(){
    displayEmplacement(0,0);
});

$("#popupDetailMoteur").css('visibility','visible');
$("#fondPopup").css('background-color','black');
centerElement($("#popupDetailMoteur"));

//demande de fermeture de la gestion des emplacements
$("#fermerPopupGestionMoteurs").click(function(){
    $("#popupDetailMoteur").css('visibility','hidden');
    $("#fondPopup").css('background-color','');
});


//gestion demande d'ajout d'un emplacement
$("#imgAddEmplacement").click(function(){

    //on récupère la liste de tous les stocks de niveau 4 maximum
    var selectOptions ='<option value="x" disabled selected>Emplacement supérieur</option><option value="0">Usine Sierre ASI</option>';

    function createSelectAddStock(stockMaster,stockLevel){
        var spaces = '';
        for (var x=0; x<stockLevel*5;x++){
            spaces+='&nbsp;';
        }
        for(var y in emplacementsFull){
            if(emplacementsFull[y]['e_nom'] != ''){
                if(emplacementsFull[y]['e_master'] == stockMaster && stockLevel<5){
                    //on l'affiche
                    selectOptions +='<option value="'+emplacementsFull[y]['e_id']+'">'+spaces+emplacementsFull[y]['e_nom']+'</option>';

                    //et on affiche ses enfants
                    createSelectAddStock(emplacementsFull[y]['e_id'],stockLevel+1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    createSelectAddStock(0,0);


    $('#ajouterEmplacement').html('<span style="display:inline-block;border:1px solid white;margin:15px;padding:10px;">'
    +'<span style="display:inline-block;"><select id="newEmplacementMaster">'+selectOptions+'</select></span><br/>'
    +'<span style="display:inline-block;"><input type="text" id="newEmplacementName"></span>'
    +'</span>');    
});
```

First view

[image: First view]

Before opening the select

[image: Before opening the select]

After opening the select

[image: After opening the select]

Comment: Might help if you put some of your HTML in a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DE49v

Comment: All the html is generated in my jquery function :S What is missing to you is the emplacementFull[] array.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by myself in another case.
Just had to set a style="width:XXXpx;"